# Joomla 3 Custom Module not able to get Data from Ajax

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Hi i am trying to set field value of an input field using ajax by calling the function from my helper.php but it does not return anything.

**Here is my mod_name.php File**

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$js = <<<JS
(function ($) {

   jQuery('#edit_sch').click(function() {
        var value   = 'cyannnnn',
            request = {
                    'option' : 'com_ajax',
                    'module' : 'helloworld',
                    'method' : 'sch',
                    'data'   : value,
                    'format' : 'raw'
                };

        jQuery.ajax({
            type   : 'POST',
            data   : request,

            success: function (response) {
                $('#edit_duration').val('dssd');
            }
        })
        return false;
    });

});(jQuery)
JS;

$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

**Here is my helper.php file**

```
<?php

class ModVedhikaSchedule {
public function schAjax()
    {


        return 'Hello Ajax World' ;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you're missing the url parameter in the ajax call function. Add the parameter and check again.